# How to search by image in a database of images?

Tags: python, node.js, image-processing, pattern-matching, artificial-intelligence

I am working with a pattern recognition logic. I tried all possible approaches but none of them working.

I tried converting the pixels to boxes and polar bins and then find `Levenshtein distance`, `Cosine Distance` etc.. But they give results when database records are a few. When database values are at range of 1000s, they don't give accurate results.

Any hint is much appreciated.

**Input:**

[image]

**Matched Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For each matched output (`_mo`), create different inputs (`_in`), *i.e.,* different ways a `_mo` can be referenced.

Keep a map of the `_in` --> `_mo`

Now for a given input from user, compute the nearest `_in` and simultaneously get `_mo` from the above map.

For similarity calculation, use deep learning approaches.

Comment: what do you mean by a map of _in --> _mo

Comment: Since there will be many variances of input, this dictionary that will finally tell you what input maps to which output.

Comment: ok, but it is impossible for me to manually draw all possible input for all shapes. They are in thousands. Is there any other solution using mathematical algo ?